# React Native Tab View _renderScene from another class

Tags: react-native

I try using Example React Native Tab View https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view. I change on const FirstRoute to call from ListMahasiswa class, but there is error : FirstRoute(...) A Valid React element (or null) must be returned.
Main.js

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { TabViewAnimated, TabBar, SceneMap } from 'react-native-tab-view';
import ListMahasiswa from './ListMahasiswa';
import InsertDataMhs from './InsertDataMhs';
import Coba from './Coba';

const FirstRoute = () => ListMahasiswa;
const SecondRoute = () => <View style={[ styles.container, { backgroundColor: '#673ab7' } ]} />;

export default class Main extends PureComponent {
  state = {
    index: 0,
    routes: [
      { key: '1', title: 'First' },
      { key: '2', title: 'Second' },
    ],
  };

  _handleChangeTab = index => this.setState({ index });

  _renderHeader = props => <TabBar {...props} />;

  _renderScene = SceneMap({
    '1': FirstRoute,
    '2': SecondRoute,
  });

  render() {
    return (
      <TabViewAnimated
        style={styles.container}
        navigationState={this.state}
        renderScene={this._renderScene}
        renderHeader={this._renderHeader}
        onRequestChangeTab={this._handleChangeTab}
      />
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

listMahasiswa.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Text,View,Button, ListView, Image, StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';

var URL="http://www.rey1024.com/api/getListMahasiswa.php";
export default  class ListMahasiswa extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    var ds = new
    ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state={
       dataSource: ds,
    };
  }

  AmbilDataMahasiswa() {
    fetch(URL)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
      this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows
        (responseData),
      });
    }) .done();
  }
  render(){
    this.AmbilDataMahasiswa();
    return(

      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
      <Text>Daftar Mahasiswa</Text>
        <ListView
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={this.renderRow}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
  renderRow(record){
    return(
      <View style={styles.row} >
        <Text>{record.nim} {record.nama}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }


}

const styles =  StyleSheet.create({
  mainContainer :{
    flex:1,
    backgroundColor:'#fff'
  },
  row :{
    borderColor: '#f1f1f1',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
    paddingTop: 20,
  },


})
```

Have any solution? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

ListMahasiswa in the following line is not a valid React element.

```
const FirstRoute = () => ListMahasiswa;
```

Try using jsx syntax instead:

```
const FirstRoute = () => <ListMahasiswa />;
```